# Problem with a simple AND SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL and given the following table *Table*, I would like to retrieve the ID values that are used by the John and Paul names (which should be 2222).

```
ID         Name
1111       John
1111       Zach
2222       John
2222       Zach
2222       Paul
3333       Zach
```

I have tried to use the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table2` WHERE Name='John' AND Name='Paul'
```

but it returns an empty set. Does anyone know an SQL statement for this without the OR statement?

Comment: Is this homework? Why avoid the use of OR?

Comment: @Ted Hopp: because the required result is when two conditions are both met simultaneously, which requires AND -- but I see the Q has been updated/corrected very recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calls for a self-join and table aliases:

```
SELECT u.ID
  FROM Table AS u
  JOIN Table AS v ON v.id = u.id
 WHERE v.name = 'John'
   AND u.name = 'Paul'
```

It joins all the pairs of ID values that are the same, and returns the ID number of those pairs where one name is 'John' and the other name is 'Paul'.

Comment: Under which circumstances do you think the DISTINCT is necessary and why?  It is not necessary for the sample data.  Further, as long as there is a primary key on the table — so that there are not two different rows with the same ID number and same name — I don't see a way in which the DISTINCT changes the result.  Granted the PK is not documented, but tables are supposed to model (mathematical) relations and those do not have duplicated rows.

Comment: in the question he say nothing about primary key.

use following queries to create and insert data to table.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table123` (
  `ID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `table123` (`ID`, `name`) VALUES
 (1111, 'John'),
 (1111, 'Zach'),
 (2222, 'John'),
 (2222, 'Zach'),
 (2222, 'Paul'),
 (3333, 'Zach'),
 (1111, 'Paul'),
 (1111, 'John'),
 (1111, 'Paul');

just try to execute your query in that table you can see prob

Comment: Tables should always have a PK and should never contain duplicate rows.  Yes, if you go with an irregular table, you might need to do things differently; if there were additional columns, you might need to do things differently.  There are all sorts of other possible circumstances that would require a different answer, but under reasonable assumptions (that the table shown is a table with a primary key), the DISTINCT is distinctly unnecessary (though it does no particular harm except to slow things down slightly).

Comment: but if you add distinct keyword then the query is always correct.. even without primary key

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Name IN ('John', 'Paul')
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Name) = 2
```

Comment: I think you misread OP's intent. This will not return ID 1111, which OP said should be included in the result set.

Comment: The required result set has been changed...1111 is not part of the result any more.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: Based on the recent edit to the question, I believe my interpretation and solution are correct.

Comment: yes, based on the recent change to the question, I would now agree that this is correct. (Of course, in my view, the change turned the problem into a completely different one.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * FROM `Table2` WHERE Name='John')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `Table2` WHERE Name='Paul')
```

Comment: No. This does not return IDs that have *both* 'John' AND 'Paul'.

Comment: @Joe - No row can ever have a name that is _both_ 'John' AND 'Paul'. It is a logical impossibility. OP clearly wants OR but for some reason doesn't want to use OR.

Comment: The ID column is not a primary key.

Comment: @Joe - Now that OP changed his original question, your point is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your difficulty is the way you have phrased the problem. If what you want is to "retrieve ID values where the name is either John or Paul", that query would look like:

```
Select ...
From Table2
Where Name = 'John'
    Or Name = 'Paul'
```

`Name = 'John' Or Name = 'Paul'` can also be written: `Name In('John','Paul')` as Paul suggested.

If what you want is to "retrieve ID values where there exists a row with the name John and there exists a row with the name Paul" then you would want to use [Joe Stefanelli's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953301/problem-with-a-simple-and-sql-statement/5953350#5953350).

Comment: OP asked for a solution _"without the OR statement"_

Comment: @Ted Hopp - The OP was having trouble first and foremost with the results not the arbitrary inclusion or avoidance of *or*. That was due primarily to the way the problem is phrased. Remember that *in* is semantically equivalent to *or* statements.

Comment: semantically equivalent, yes. But OP specifically asked for solutions that did not use OR. (Perhaps a homework problem?)

Answer (score 0):

i think u should put the name of the table in [] .. [Table2] not 'Table2'

Comment: The back tick character is used in mysql the way square brackets are used in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID
FROM Table2
WHERE Name IN ('John','Paul')

Answer (score 0):

Use following query

```
select distinct(t1.ID) from table123  t1 , table123 t2 where t1.ID=t2.ID and t1.name='John' and
 t2.name='Paul' ;
```